# Bad function assignation

Tags: typescript, typechecking

I get a problem in non strict mode, Here is my code
I can assign a function with bad type to a typed variable.

Do I make a mistake ?

Thanks.

```
interface A {
    f1( ) : void;
}

interface B extends A {
    f2( ) : void;
}

interface C {
    f3( ) : void;
}

type expectA = ( a: A ) => void;
type expectB = ( b: B ) => void;


function testA( a: A ) {
    console.log( "a" );
}

function testB( b: B ) {
    console.log( "b" );
}

function testC( c: C ) {
    console.log( "c" );
}


let v1: expectA = testA;    // ok: assign type A to a type A
let v2: expectA = testB;    // ok: assign type B (extending A) to a type A
let v3: expectA = testC;    // fail -> normal: error TS2322: Type '(c: C) => void' is not assignable to type 'expectA'.
let v4: expectB = testA;    // ok -> **abnormal**: there is no error in !strict mode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is actually protecting you against doing something silly here, but it's doing so in a confusing way.

Let's reduce your example to just the interfaces `A` and `B`.

```
interface A {
    f1( ) : void;
}

interface B extends A {
    f2( ) : void;
}

type expectA = ( a: A ) => void;
type expectB = ( b: B ) => void;


function testA( a: A ) {
    a.f1();
}

function testB( b: B ) {
    b.f1();
    b.f2();
}


const v1: expectA = testA;
const v2: expectA = testB; // error: Property 'f2' is missing in type 'A' but required in type 'B'
const v3: expectB = testB;
const v4: expectB = testA;
```

On first glance, the result at the bottom where only `v2` has an error might seem counterintuitive. If `B` extends `A`, then why can't you use `B` *everywhere* you can use `A`?

The answer is because we're dealing with functions here. Look closely at the implementation of `testB()`. It calls the property `b.f2()` because it expects that its parameter `b` will have that property. But the left hand side of `const v2: expectB` is equivalent to the type `(a: A) => void`. The parameter of type `A` does *not* have `f2()`. So we're telling TypeScript conflicting things about what the proper type of `v2` is; either it's a function that has `a: A` in which case `a.f2()` is *not* safe to call, or it's a function that has `b: B` in which case it *is* safe. It's a paradox!

(Keep in mind that this has nothing to do with whether `testB` *actually* tries to call `b.f2()`; the point is that it *could*, based on how its argument types are set, which would cause a runtime error in the `v2` scenario.)

Now for `const v4` you say you think it's "abnormal" that this would be OK, but if we look carefully at the functions again we can see that it makes sense that it is OK. If you passed *either* a type `A` or `B` variable to `testA()`, there are no possible errors because it will *never* try to access the `f2()` property.

Note also that `extends` does not work in TypeScript quite the way you might expect it to. Writing `interface B extends A` simply says that `B` will inherit all the properties of `A`. It does not establish any kind of relationship allowing `B` to stand in for any instance of `A`. Such behavior is called "polymorphism" and to do that you would need to use classes instead, e.g. `class B extends A implements A`.

```
class A {
    foo = '';
}

class B extends A implements A {
    bar = '';
}

let isA = new A();
isA = new B(); // this is fine because B implements A
let isB = new B();
isB = new A(); // error: Property 'bar' is missing in type 'A' but required in type 'B'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this response but,
In fact my question was about strict/vs non strict mode.
(I made a small error in my initial description sorry for that)

When I said non strict mode, I mean without this option in tsconfig.json

```
"strict": true, /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
```

With your simplified version:

```
interface A {
    f1( ) : void;
}

interface B extends A {
    f2( ) : void;
}

type expectA = ( a: A ) => void;
  
function testB( b: B ) {
    console.log( "b" );
    b.f1();
    b.f2();
}
    
// here in strict mode there is an error and that's ok 
// but in non strict mode there is no error
let v2: expectA = testB;    // error TS2322: Type '(b: B) => void' is not assignable to type 'expectA'.

class ClassB implements B {
    f1( ) {}
    f2( ) {}
}

let t = new ClassB( );
v2( t );
```

I do not understand why this line is allowed in non strict mode.
It is allowed just because there is a relationship between B interface & A interface. If you remove this inheritance, the compiler is complaining.

```
let v2: expectA = testB
```